# Reshape N 2-d matrices (T*M) into a 3d tensor of (T*N*M) with tidyverse/R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, reshape2

For each of my N variables, I have a (T * M) feature matrix, i.e., M observations per t \in T.  The problem is how to convert this into a (T * N * M) array. For example, in the following example N=2, T=3, M=4 :

```
x1 <- matrix(1:24, 3,4)
> x1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12


x2 <- matrix(25:48, 3,4)
x2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   25   28   31   34
[2,]   26   29   32   35
[3,]   27   30   33   36
```

And I need to make a 3 dimensional (number of rows) array, such that the first element is

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]   25   28   31   34
```

and the second is:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    5    8   11
[2,]   26   29   32   35
```

and third:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    6    9   12
[2,]   27   30   33   36
```

and so on and so forth. For the following example, the output's dimensions should be (3,2,4).

I need to do this for relatively large N and T, so appreciate extendable implementations!

Comment: @markus Thank you, I've edited the tags accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `base R` option.

```
out <- `dim<-`(rbind(c(t(x1)), c(t(x2))), c(2, 4, 3))
out
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    4    7   10
#[2,]   25   28   31   34
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    2    5    8   11
#[2,]   26   29   32   35
#
#, , 3
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3    6    9   12
#[2,]   27   30   33   36
```

---

When we call `x <- rbind(c(t(x1)), c(t(x2)))` we get the following matrix as a result

```
x
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#[1,]    1    4    7   10    2    5    8   11    3     6     9    12
#[2,]   25   28   31   34   26   29   32   35   27    30    33    36
```

We need to change the dimensions of this object for which we can do

```
dim(x) <- c(2, 4, 3)
```

Another way to get the same result is to call the replacement method of `dim` in its [functional form](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#all-calls), i.e.

```
`dim<-`(...)
```

Which allows us to do all in one line.

Comment: Thanks! do you mind explaining how this works? Specifically, I had not encountered `dim<-` in such form before

Comment: @Alex added some explanation. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Maybe not directly related, but I need the dimensions to be c(3,2,4) for Keras (3 samples, each 2*4). I can't seem to do it via dim or aperm; it messes up the order. Would you know how to do this?

Comment: But doesn't the solution give you desired output?

Comment: The above solution returns c(2, 4, 3), which implies 2 samples each 4*3

Comment: Not sure I can follow you: above, the `2` refers to the number of rows, the `4` is the number of columns and the `3` is the third dimension. So you get a three dimensional array, each element having to rows and four columns. Just like you showed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191821/discussion-between-alex-and-markus).